# What addrtype is to be used for only forwarded packets?

Tags: iptables

To "focus" an iptables rule on packets destined for the current host, we use "LOCAL", so which should we use for those destined for another host? The documentation is unclear regarding this (correct me if I am wrong). I am seeing one called "NAT" but if my memory serves me right it's no longer supported.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to do a "--jump" from the FORWARD chain to a custom chain in the NAT table but sadly FORWARD is in the FILTER table and not the NAT table. So, to the best of my knowledge, my only option is to use POSTROUTING (and singling out packets to be forwarded) which is in the NAT table.

Comment: Sorry, let me try again. That's an implementation. What end goal are you trying to reach?

Comment: The goal is to have istio also intercept packets destined for another host, Istio's current implementation does `OUTPUT --jump ISTIO_OUTPUT` but to achieve what I need I would need to do `FORWARD --jump ISTIO_OUTPUT` which isnt possible since FORWARD is in the filter table and istio's custom ISTIO_OUTPUT is in the nat table.

Comment: Intercept them from what? TCP? UDP? ICMP? From a particular source or network? Destined for some specific port? To be forwarded/redirected to a particular host and port?

Comment: Avoid talking about _how_ you think you want to solve the problem, please, and describe _what_ the underlying problem is that you need to solve

Comment: The goal is to have istio also intercept packets destined for another host, currently it only intercept those originating from the host. In regard to protocol, only TCP as it's the only one supported by istio at the moment. Istio uses iptables rule.

Comment: Your comment is enough to guess the answer to the title (but not sure about answering to the potential [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)): tcp doesn't support broadcast or multicast. What's left?

Comment: @A.B, unicast/local, I eventually figured it out after some proper sleep, "addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL" for those destined for another host, I intend to answer the question later today when I'm settled